# roxygen templates from a different location

Tags: r, roxygen2

Is there a way how to call roxygen templates from a different location, other than the current package?

**Use Case**

I have a lot of packages. Many of them use the same templates for documentation.
If a change is needed in one of the templates, I would like to do it in one place and not have to update multiple packages.

**Ideal Solution** *(in my view at the moment)*

I have a package, that I'm using for utility functions used across multiple packages. As a part of that package I would have roxygen templates in man-roxygen folder. And I would like to reference templates from this location in other packages.

**Insufficient solutions**

1. Symbolic link to a directory: Not solving the case when some extra templates are needed for individual packages, which shouldn't be in the central repository. (unless I can have more man-roxygen like directories)
2. Symbolic links to individual files: A hassle of creating such a stuff. And mainly symbolic links are not a solution when SVN is used on multiple platforms including Windows.
3. Templates inside calling a packageABC::functionXYZ() that returns the text. Cumbersome and it doesn't solve the need to copy files to individual packages.